# How to fetch all music apps name contains in device

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have to fetch all music apps name contains in device (like google play,gaana,saavan) and has to show all name in my app. I search a lot but not able to find a solution.Please help me if anyone has an idea.
                        Is there any way to fetch downloaded music files or list from iTunes store?

Comment: iOS doesn't allow this. This is not what you have asked for but you can use share extension to see what all apps are supported by apps on the device. If you want to open a music file then using Share Extension iOS will show all the apps which can open this file.

Answer (score 0):

iOS applications are installed in Sandboxed environment, meaning that **they cannot do anything outside their own application**. It may work on Jailbroken devices! 
*More details given in this* [*link*](http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/22289-possible-retrieve-these-information.html),